# AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address

Tags: c++, dictionary, runtime-error

Im trying to write a function to determine if the input string is valid. 
This task is from leetcode, 20th task. So its given like that.

```
Given a string containing just the characters '(', ')', '{', '}', '[' and ']', determine if the input string is valid.
An input string is valid if:
*Open brackets must be closed by the same type of brackets.
*Open brackets must be closed in the correct order.
Note that an empty string is also considered valid.
```

My code:

```
bool isValid(string s) {
        vector<char> str;
        map<char, char> mp;
        mp['{']='}';
        mp['(']=')';
        mp['[']=']';
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            str.push_back(s[i]);
        }int c = 0;
        while(!str.empty()){
            c++;
            for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++){
                if(str[i+1]==mp[i]){
                    int x = i+1;
                    str.erase(str.begin()+x);
                    str.erase(str.begin()+i);
                    }
            }if(c>str.size()) break;
        }
        if(str.empty()) return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

But every time I get this error:

```
=================================================================
==32==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000032 at pc 0x00000038767f bp 0x7ffffae90390 sp 0x7ffffae90388
READ of size 1 at 0x602000000032 thread T0
    #2 0x7fd5e106882f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
0x602000000032 is located 0 bytes to the right of 2-byte region [0x602000000030,0x602000000032)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #4 0x7fd5e106882f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c047fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c047fff8000: fa fa fd fa fa fa[02]fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8010: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==32==ABORTING
```

Can you explain, whats wrong here, does my solution correct or not?

Comment: You are removing elements from `str` as you are iterating through it, which means you'll likely index out of bounds at some point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing to `mp[i]` does not make any sense.

Since `mp` does not initially contain 0,1,2,3,... but three brackets, `mp[i]` will be zero until your index happens to be the encoding of one of the opening bracket characters (the first one is very likely 40, `'('` in ASCII).

What will happen if you don't have that many characters is that you reach the last iteration, when `i == size() - 1`.
Then accessing `str[i+1]` has undefined behaviour and anything can happen.

There is no simple way to repair your program because your approach is flawed to begin with, so I would recommend that you delete all of that and start over.
(At a minimum, you need a way to keep track of all the opening brackets you've encountered so far. Major hint: read about `std::stack`)